# HTML Input attribute disabled doesn't react to state change condition

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, attributes, state

I have an issue where the condition that enables or disables input field through HTML attribute according to the React state only works for the first time. I don't know if this is a limit and it has to be done differently or I am missing something in a sea of unexpected behavior with JS React and state.

I have following fields isFixedAmount and fixedAmount. The first one is boolean while the second is a number.

I get them from the DB on a component mount and show them in the form. If the IsFixedAmount is false I want to disable the input field for fixedAmount.

```
   <label>Is Fixed Amount</label>
   <select 
    value={isFixedAmount} 
    onChange={(e) => setIsFixedAmount(e.target.value)}
   >
      <option value={true}>Yes</option>
      <option value={false}>No</option>
   </select>

   <label>Fixed Amount</label>
   <input 
     type="number" 
     name="fixedAmount" 
     disabled={isFixedAmount ? false : true} 
     value={fixedAmount} 
     onChange={(e) => setFixedAmount(e.target.value)} 
   />
```

On the first render I get the correct result. I can change one time and it works, however every next change leaves the input field as with the last change.

When I inspect it through Components in ReactDevTools I see state value for isFixedAmount properly changing with each selection but the input field disabled attribute is not doing anything after the first change, it's like it is not listening to it anymore.

Comment: Has nothing to do with your question but think about using semantically correct HTML. The way you have it structured right now your `<label>`s are useless. They need a `for=""` attribute to tell the browser which field they belong to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the values passed in select input are passed as strings.

You can do
       `onChange={() => setIsFixedAmount((previousState) => !previousState)}`

Comment: Thank you for proposing the solution, it works with the proposed approach

Answer (score 1):

Because the `select` element only accept string | number | read-only string[] type so that the `isFixedAmount` became the string type when you selected.

So the input of `disabled` is always false.

You can see this at here : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-8pzzwr?file=App.tsx)
[image]

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I now understand better what happened.

Answer (score 1):

i think isFixedAmount value is string so it doesn't work properly so you need to change the code on

```
<input 
     type="number" 
     name="fixedAmount" 
     disabled={isFixedAmount === 'true' ? false : true} 
     value={fixedAmount} 
     onChange={(e) => setFixedAmount(e.target.value)} 
   />
```

for example console the value it has to be a string `typeof(e.target.value)`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).